# Hide grouped/configured product with zero visible sub-products

Tags: magento2, catalog, magento2.2.2, inventory, grouped-products

I have a site running *Magento EE 2.2.2* and I have lots of Grouped and Configured Products. I turned off "Display Out of Stock Products". As expected, when a sub-product is out of stock, it is not displayed.

However, when all the sub-products of a given grouped-product are out of stock, it still displays the parent grouped product with no sub-products listed.

**How do I hide grouped or configured products whose sub-products are all out of stock?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, on upload, the sub-products or "child items" were set as hidden for that particular site, but the grouped products or "master items" were not set as hidden. They were still visible though out of stock. This seems to have overridden the *Hide Out of Stock Items* feature of Magento.

The Stock management is working fine, and all settings were configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

`Display Out of Stock Products` is the correct setting for this, and it need to be set `NO` for your requirement. However if it is not working you might look configuration setting scope, whether it may be set `YES` for the particular store scope.

Comment: `Display Out of Stock Products` is set to `NO` for scope on all stores. And that works for single products and for the sub-products of group products. But the group products still show up even when all the sub-products are hidden. I guess maybe this setting doesn't affect the grouped product because they don't have their own quantity? Is there a way around this?

Comment: if all the child products are out of stock the parent product should automatically reset as out of stock. Can you check what is the stock status of the group product and if anyhow "Back order" is enabled?

Comment: All child products are out of stock, and the grouped product says `In Stock` for field `Stock Status`. However on the site, the item says "No options of this product are available" and for quantity says "Out of Stock."